# Ethernet link issue between PC and embedded DAQ card

Tags: udp, embedded, ethernet, lan

I have an embedded DAQ card that streams data over ethernet using udp multicast protocol. Between that card and my PC there is a network switch. I have two setup like this. The PC send a udp command that starts the traffic from the embedded card.

With the first setup, if I disconnect and then reconnect the DAQ card from the switch I lost the link (the led of the switch is off).

In the other setup I'm able to disconnect and reconnect the DAQ card from the switch as many times as I want: when I reconnect the cable I receive data again.
Is the first setup normal, or the second? The PC is the same, what changes is the DAQ card (but I verifyed that the firmware version is the same) and the cable (and I cannot try to use the same because the card and the cable are molded together with resin). I'm trying to figure out what's the issue: eth cable, nic configuration, .....

Comment: If it is not a problem with _your_ code, it is off-topic on StackOverflow.  Wherever you ask this however, someone is going to what to know the specific of your DAQ - it is a generic term and does not describe the specific hardware - manufacture, part number, firmware version etc. would be useful.  I strongly suggest in any event you contact the manufacturer's support fist.  It is likely to be very specific to their implementation.

Comment: One card configured to use DHCP and the other not?

Comment: yes. maybe it could be the cause!